# Cómo acceder a los elementos de un vector de registros (punteros) en posiciones no consecutivas en C

Tags: c, array, punteros

Lo que hace esta función es crear un vector de registros que apunten a otros bloques que son registros (apuntando estos a otros regs, un poco lío, sí). Y al haber reservado memoria dinámica en la variable "vector_registrosRef", las posiciones de memoria no son consecutivas. He aquí el esquema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que no sé es cómo acceder a cada elemento del vector_registrosRef si no están en posiciones consecutivas de memoria. Lo que estaría haciendo entonces sería una matriz bidimensional en memoria dinámica.
Aquí el código:

```
tipoEmpleado **
crearRegistrosRef(int numEmpleados, int *errNum)
{
  int i;
  tipoEmpleado **vector_registrosRef;
  tipoEmpleado *vector_registros;

  if (numEmpleados <= 0) {
    *errNum = -1;
     return NULL;
  }

  else if (NULL == (vector_registrosRef = (tipoEmpleado **)calloc(numEmpleados, sizeof(tipoEmpleado)))) {
    *errNum = -2;
    free(vector_registrosRef);
    return NULL;
  }

  vector_registros = (tipoEmpleado *) calloc(numEmpleados, sizeof(tipoEmpleado))));
  for (i = 0; i < numEmpleados; i++) {
    if (NULL == vector_registros[i]) {
    *errNum = -3;
    free(vector_registros);
    return NULL;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numEmpleados; i++) {
    vector_registrosRef[i] = &(vector_registros[i]);
  }

  *errNum = 0;

  return vector_registrosRef;
}
```

Utilice un typedef para definir un tipo struct, aquí el struct tipoEmpleado:

```
typedef struct empleados {
  char apellidos[30];
  char nombre[15];
  int matricula;
  char bufferRelleno[5];
} tipoEmpleado;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes implementado en el código no se corresponde con la figura.

Veamos lo que vas construyendo, paso a paso:

```
tipoEmpleado **vector_registrosRef;
```

Ya que `tipoEmpleado` es un "registro", esta declaración dice que la variable es un puntero, que apunta a una zona de memoria donde hay un puntero a un registro. De momento coincide con la figura.

```
tipoEmpleado *vector_registros;
```

Esta otra declaración es un puntero a un registro. En principio cada uno de los elementos del vector (señalo uno en rojo) sería de este tipo (`tipoEmpleado *`) Sin embargo como veremos no lo usas de esta forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comenzamos a reservar memoria, este es el primer `calloc()` (eliminando la comprobación de error):

```
vector_registrosRef = (tipoEmpleado **)calloc(numEmpleados, sizeof(tipoEmpleado))
```

Aquí ya vemos algo mal. A `calloc()` debes pasarle el número de elementos, que está correcto, y el tamaño de cada uno, que está mal pues has puesto `sizeof(tipoEmpleado)`, como si cada uno de los elementos que marqué en rojo en la figura fuese un registro. En realidad ha de ser un puntero a registro, por lo que tendrías que haber escrito `sizeof(tipoEmpleado*)`.

Lo siguiente que tendría que hacer el código es iterar en un bucle para ir creando (con `malloc()`) espacio *para cada uno de los registros*, e ir guardando en el vector anterior los punteros resultantes. No es eso lo que haces, sino:

```
vector_registros = (tipoEmpleado *) calloc(numEmpleados, sizeof(tipoEmpleado))))
```

Es decir, creas espacio para `numEmpleados` registros, pero todo ello en un solo `calloc()` y por tanto *en un bloque de memoria contiguo*. En realidad, si comparas este `calloc()` con el primero, verás que ambos reciben los mismos parámetros. ¡Ambos están creando una zona de memoria contigua para almacenar `numEmpleados` registros!

La situación en este momento, gráficamente, sería:

[image: De momento mal]

A continuación tienes un extraño bucle:

```
  for (i = 0; i < numEmpleados; i++) {
    if (NULL == vector_registros[i]) {
    *errNum = -3;
    free(vector_registros);
    return NULL;
    }
  }
```

Ya que `vector_registros` apunta a una zona de memoria contigua donde tenemos espacio reservado para registros (tal como se ve en la figura anterior), `vector_registros[i]` es una expresión válida, que accedería a la i-ésima entrada en esa zona de memoria. Pero lo que hay allí es un registro, no un puntero, por lo que no tiene sentido compararlo con `NULL` como has hecho. Además, aún si fuera posible esa comparación, te daría "True", porque `calloc()` ha inicializado con ceros toda la zona de memoria reservada, y el cero es un equivalente a NULL cuando se interpreta como puntero (aunque, insisto, en este caso no cabe esa interpretación).

Ignoremos por tanto el bucle anterior cuyo cometido no tengo claro.

Después tenemos este otro bucle:

```
  for (i = 0; i < numEmpleados; i++) {
    vector_registrosRef[i] = &(vector_registros[i]);
  }
```

el cual también está mal, puesto que `vector_registrosRef`, como se ha visto, apunta a una zona donde hay registros, no donde hay punteros. Pero la estás usando como si hubiera punteros (los punteros ocupan menos que los registros, así que no estás usando esa zona al completo, sobraría mucho espacio).

La figura que resultaría no sería como la que buscamos, sino algo más parecido a esto (lo gris es memoria reservada pero no usada):

[image: Mal]

## Solución

Para implementar correctamente una reserva de memoria que responda a la figura que pegaste, tienes que reservar primero espacio para N punteros, no para N registros. Después en un bucle que se repita N veces, reservar memoria para un solo registro de cada vez, y hacer apuntar cada elemento del primer vector de punteros a la zona reservada.

Este sería el esqueleto básico que tendrías que completar con el manejo de errores, etc.

```
tipoEmpleado **
crearRegistrosRef(int numEmpleados, int *errNum)
{
  int i;
  tipoEmpleado **vector_registrosRef;

  vector_registrosRef = (tipoEmpleado **)calloc(numEmpleados, sizeof(tipoEmpleado *));

  for (i = 0; i < numEmpleados; i++) {
    vector_registrosRef[i] = (tipoEmpleado *) calloc(1, sizeofTipoEmpleado));
  }
  return vector_registrosRef;
}
```

Si llamamos a la función anterior por ejemplo así:

```
tipoEmpleado **p = crearRegistrosRef(20, ...);
```

para posteriormente acceder por ejemplo al nombre del empleado i-ésimo la sintaxis sería:

```
printf("Nombre: %s\n", p[i]->nombre);
```

La sintaxis `->` se usa cuando a la izquierda de la flecha tenemos un *puntero a estructura*, y en ese caso podemos poner a la derecha de la flecha el nombre de un campo de la estructura para acceder a él.

Esa sintaxis es equivalente a `(*p[i]).nombre`. Elige la que más te guste.